# AppEngine - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spotify, reddit

I'm making a web app with **AppEngine** that uses the **Spotify** and **Reddit** APIs and have it working locally with `dev_appserver.py`, but when I upload my project and try the exact same thing on the website version, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
...
...

  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~kabloombox-219016/20190116t005128.415435515961651480/main.py", line 274, in post
    scan_subreddit(language, access_token)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~kabloombox-219016/20190116t005128.415435515961651480/main.py", line 190, in scan_subreddit
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=CLIENT_ID_REDDIT, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_REDDIT, user_agent=USER_AGENT)
...
...

  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 165, in libc_ver
    f = open(executable,'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_dist/python'
```

I get this error after submitting a form, which then is supposed to run a web scraper but just errors instantly instead. I found a lot of people with the same `No such file or directory` error on their own files that they made and just needed to change app.yaml, but `/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/350d926c06a7e859/python27/python27_dist/python` is some random `file/folder` and I have absolutely no idea what I'm supposed to make of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change your praw initialization to prevent it from calling platform.platform():

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='...', disable_update_check=True)
```

Or patch platform.platform() to return a string literal in **appengine_config.py**:

```
import platform

def patch(module):
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(module, func.func_name, func)
        return func
    return decorate

@patch(platform)
def platform():
    return 'AppEngine'
```

Comment: Hi, patching platform worked for me! The only change I made to the code was having a random parameter for the platform() function, since I got the error `TypeError: platform() takes no arguments (1 given)`. Thanks for the help!